# Dired: Duplicate Files (the operation, not how to get rid of 'em)

Tags: emacs, dired

Sometimes I want to create a duplicate of a number of files (say, config files), which initially should have the same content as the initial files. Therefore I'd like to be able mark some files in dired and "duplicate" them, this duplication procedure could work similar like the duplication procedure utilised by most file managers, when pasting to the original directory: The file names of the duplicated get "(Copy)" appended (just before the file extension).

I can't seem to find a built-in dired function that does this, maybe someone can help/has already created a function like this?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you will want to rename the functions (I didn't come up with better names), maybe some more elaborate formatting, if you wish...

```lisp
(defcustom dired-keep-marker-version ?V
  "Controls marking of versioned files.
If t, versioned files are marked if and as the corresponding original files were.
If a character, copied files are unconditionally marked with that character."
  :type '(choice (const :tag "Keep" t)
         (character :tag "Mark"))
  :group 'dired-mark)

(defun dired-version-file (from to ok-flag)
  (dired-handle-overwrite to)
  (dired-copy-file-recursive from to ok-flag dired-copy-preserve-time t
                 dired-recursive-copies))

(defun dired-do-version (&optional arg)
  "Search for numeric pattern in file name and create a version of that file
with that number incremented by one, or, in case such file already exists,
will search for a file with the similar name, incrementing the counter each
time by one.
Additionally, if called with prefix argument, will prompt for number format.
The formatting is the same as is used with `format' function."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((fn-list (dired-get-marked-files nil nil)))
    (dired-create-files
     (function dired-version-file) "Version" fn-list
     (function
      (lambda (from)
        (let (new-name (i 0) (fmt (if arg (read-string "Version format: " "%d") "%d")))
          (while (or (null new-name) (file-exists-p new-name))
            (setq new-name
                  (if (string-match  "^\\([^0-9]*\\)\\([0-9]+\\)\\(.*\\)$" from)
                      (concat (match-string 1 from)
                              (format fmt
                                      (+ (string-to-number (match-string 2 from)) (1+ i)))
                              (match-string 3 from))
                    (concat from (format (concat "." fmt) i)))
                  i (1+ i))) new-name)))
     dired-keep-marker-version)))

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "c") 'dired-do-version)
```

Also, I've originally used <kbd>v</kbd> to bind this function because I don't use `dired-view`, but you would need to bind that inside `dired`s hook. <kbd>c</kbd> just was the first undefined key, so I used it.

Comment: Yes! Definitely a very cool snippet as well! I thought of two additions: 1) If called with prefix `C-u` ask for string to put instead of number, and 2) Check whether version already exists and increment accordingly. I don't know how complex and time-consuming adding those features might be....

Comment: @elemakil currently it will prompt you to rename the file, if the newly created name exists... perhaps there may be an automatic resolution though... I'll take a look at it later today. While writing this snippet I've discovered what is the default behavior of many `dired` commands... :) `C-u` for them means that if there is a marked directory, it will use that directory as a target. But, certainly, it can do more with the prefix. I'll tinker with it more this evening.

Comment: @elemakil well, both things proved to be easier then I thought. It seems to work in general, but if notice any issues with it, you are welcome to alert me :) It doesn't seem like this function can do any harm, as it doesn't delete files, neither overwrites, but I'd still be careful, just in case.

Answer (score 11):

There is one function that does what you want: `dired-do-copy-regexp`

Example of use:

1. mark the files
2. `M-x dired-do-copy-regexp`
3. `\(.*\)\.\(.*\)`
4. `\1 (copy).\2`

For a file named foo.txt you will be creating another named foo (copy).txt

Note that my first regexp has two groups, and the second regexp references them.  You can do much more complicated things, if needed.

Comment: I like this! Nice and easy and reminds me that I should always try something with regexps before posting a question on SO... ;-) However, I gues this can't be extended to automagically detect whether there's already a `(copy)` present (not the file which is marked) and if this is true appends more `(copy)` strings until the filename is unique? [Not that I would ever really use that... your initial solution is sufficient, however I'm curious].

Comment: If you want to handle the case where a copy is present, you should take a look to the variables `dired-backup-overwrite` (from dired-aux.el), and `backup-directory-alist`.  The former controls if making backups before overwriting files, the later is about how to name the backups.

Comment: Point 3 looks like a group of cheerleaders

Answer (score 2):

In the Dired mode, put cursor on the file you want to duplicate or mark that file, then press "C". You will be prompted for new name.

You can use this feature to copy files between Dired buffers as well. To make it possible put into your init file:
`(setq dired-dwim-target t)`

Comment: But with this you can't duplicate multiple files. -Or, I haven't figured out how to rename the multiple files